# SQL Query Unable to Compute

Tags: c#, sql-server

My SQL query is unable to compute the exact `OTAmount`. I tried to query it to SQL Server the query looks fine. The only thing I change is the `HRate` variable.

```
decimal DR=0;
decimal HRate = 0;

if (rdSal.HasRows)
{
     rdSal.Read();
     DR = Convert.ToDecimal(rdSal.GetString(2));
     HRate = DR / 8;
}

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
cmd3.Connection = con;
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd3.CommandText = "Insert Into Overtime ([EMPID],[Date],[OTMins], 
[OTAmount],[DayofWeek])Select UserID,Date,DateDiff(minute,TimeIn,TimeOut), 
(DateDiff(minute,TimeIn,TimeOut)/60.00)*1.25*"+HRate+",DayofWeek from 
UserLog where DayofWeek='Saturday' and USERID='" + val + "'AND DATE>='" + 
codatebegintxt.Text + "'AND DATE<='" + codateendtxt.Text + "'";

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Yes. How can we help you ?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: What error you are receiving while running this code?

Comment: TimeIn & TimeOut are varchar thats why it will accept the values on codatebegintxt.Text & codateendtxt.Text it works find my problem is the HRate if i replace it with a value like (DateDiff(minute,TimeIn,TimeOut)/60.00)*1.25*96.15375 it will compute the exact result

Comment: is there any reason for using decimal? if you are using parameterised thing, you can specify precision etc, else you can use float/double etc.

Comment: I am using decimal because int will not have decimal numbers, I already used double also

Answer (score 0):

Can you change you DR to:

```
DR = Convert.ToDecimal(rdSal.GetString(2), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

and `HRate = DR / 8.0` instead of `HRate = DR / 8`.

Else as indicated it in comments, can you change it to:

```
string query = "Insert Into Overtime (EMPID, Date, OTMins, 
OTAmount, DayofWeek) Select UserID, Date, DateDiff (minute,TimeIn,TimeOut), 
(DateDiff(minute,TimeIn,TimeOut)/60.00) * 1.25 * @HRate, DayofWeek from 
UserLog where DayofWeek = 'Saturday' and USERID = @UserId AND DATE >= 
@DateBegin AND DATE <= @DateEnd";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HRate", HRate); // can specify precision and scale with .Precision and .Scale.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", val);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateBegin", codatebegintxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateEnd", codateendtxt.Text);
```

and replace the commandtext by adding @ in front of variables. (Hope its not confusing).

Comment: see above and try with parameters.

Comment: already used cmd Parameters AddWithValue and replace command text with @H Rate , @User Id still not the exact result

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...